# IOS 5 SDK and Segues

Tags: ios5, storyboard

I am creating a project with Xcode 4.2 and using it's storyboard.  In one of the views I have a button that a user will tap and it will perform some calculations.  If the calculations are correct I need to display the view that they just came from.  I am currently using a Navigation Controller.  When the app starts it loads View 1.  When I choose an option it loads View 2.  If I click the 'back' button in the toolbar it loads View 1 with left animation.

In my IBAction method for the View 2 calculation I have the following snippet.

```
[self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"BackToView1" sender:sender];
```

But the problem is it loads View 1 using the left animation when I need it to load the right.

Would that be a custom segue?  Am I missing something?

[Edit]
I just noticed something as well.  When View 1 loads from my IBAction it appears it is initializing the AppDelegate again, whereas the 'back' button does not.  I need to not initialize the AppDelegate since I am loading a data object at the start of the app.  Calling init again kills my object.

Comment: Each arrow in the storyboard represents creating and displaying a new instance of a view controller.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could try using the navigation controller to pop back. This will probably produce the effect you are after.

```
[self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:YES];
```

Comment: Sweet.  That did the trick.  I assumed I had to use the segue with IOS 5.  You know what happens when you assume :)  Thanks

Comment: You are free to mix storyboards with all other techniques

Comment: if you are looking for a quick FAQ on storyboards:  http://2cupsoftech.wordpress.com/2012/09/17/faq-on-ios5-storyboard